# C# private method boolean

Tags: c#, boolean

I need help adding a private method that returns a boolean of type interger.
If the parameter is < 50 then it should return the value false, else return

I am currently experimenting with c# and used an if else statement but need to use get, set

```
private static bool AmHungry
if size < 50;
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

I've tried using get set accessors but how would I be able to define the value that needs to be met to decide the boolean answer?

Answer (score 1):

In order to define any value, you will need to save it into another variable. In order to use it, you then call that variable.

```
public static int HungerThreshold { get; set; }    // Using this creates anthe imlicit field and simple access at compile time
publis static bool AmHungry
{
    get { return size < HungerThreshold; } // Forget not that compaison operators return bool, and can thus be returned directly instead of using an if/else
}
```

Also don't forget that methods always need `()` and `{}`, and properties always need `{}`